# Wrong default organisation

Tags: default-settings

I choosed as default organisation an individual instead an organisation.
Can I change this or is there a solution?

Thousand thanks for your help.

Regard, Oliver

Answer (score 5):

You can update the default information under **Administer > Communications > Organization Address and Contact Info** in the CiviCRM menu.

[image: Default org info]