# Change Default Organization

Tags: contacts, configuration

I am on CiviCRM 4.4.9. I have followed the instructions for "Moving an Existing Installation to a New Server." When I open the Civicrm in the new location, it appears that it is setting the default organization to my contact (my contact ID is 1) instead of the organization's contact ID which is 26299. My contact has about 58K of activities; the organization's activities are 2.

How do I change the default organization to the proper contact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set it in Administer > Communications > Organization Address and Contact Info, as per: [Wrong default organisation](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2396/wrong-default-organisation)

ETA: As I just went through the process of transferring to a new server, I've realised that the instructions result in your original civicrm_domain being skipped in the MySQL dump. A fresh install of CiviCRM on the new server will assign the contact id 1 to the default organisation in the civicrm_domain table - you can get around his by either including civicrm_domain in the initial SQL dump, or by editing the contact_id field in the new database's civicrm_domain table.

Comment: Yeah, I know. The problem is not the address, but all the historical data including the activities is for the wrong contact.

The original CiviCRM install has contact id 26299 as the default organization, so there must be a way to set the default organization to a certain contact ID.

Comment: Set it as above and if you end up with two identical orgs, merge them.

Comment: That might be a work-around. I just don't understand why CiviCRM sets the default organization as an individual's record. Shouldn't it only set the default organization as an organization-type contact?

Comment: @HarryJ, I haven't seen that happen so don't have specific insight -- do you share an email address with the org? But a new server shouldn't affect the database in that way.

Comment: It looks like fresh installs assign the CiviCRM ID #1 to the default organisation, rather than the primary administrator. I'm not sure why this would affect a transferred installation, but assuming you installed a fresh version and then overwrote the database with your original data, it's possible the error slipped in at that point if you used phpmyadmin to export/import your db, as one of the tables you may have skipped, along with the cache tables, is civicrm_domain. But I'm not familiar enough with the scheme to be sure, and I don't know if that would apply if you're not using phpmyadmin...

Comment: Just checked the wiki, and civicrm_domain is ignored in the MySQL dump. But I would have expected it to come up as an error more often - I suppose it depends when the system started assigning the id to the default org.

Comment: @liblogger. I used the procedure [link](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location). I did a MySQL dump of my data and reimported it into the new site. I did not use phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @Laryn: Cannot merge the default 'organization' as the current default organization is an individual and the actual default organization is an organization-type contact.

Comment: @HarryJ Try this: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/21/26

Comment: If you don't want to change your record into an organisation, you can either re-do the initial MySQL dump without skipping the civicrm_domain, or do what I just did, which is change the contact_id in the current civicrm_domain table to the id of your organisation's contact record. (Must remember that this happens next time I have to move servers!)

Comment: @liblogger: You are the man! I edited the civicrm_domain contact_id to the ID of my organization, which changed the default organization to the proper record.

Comment: @Laryn: During the testing, my personal record got changed to the default organization. Using the link above, after changing the default organization to the proper record, I was able to change my personal record using the link you provided. 

Thank you both very much.